# Rails form date_field is showing mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Before I input anything into the rails form. The date_field is showing `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Is their a way for it to show `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Placeholder doesn't work.

I have looked around for an answer but none of the answers worked.

Thank you.

Here is the form data.

```
.flex.flex-column.w50p.mx-auto
  = form_for :agreegated_answer, url: survey_aggregated_answers_path(@survey), method: :post  do |f|
    = f.label :procedures_that_have_tags
    = f.collection_select(:tag_ids, @survey.tags, :name, :name, { selected: [] },
      multiple: true, class: 'js-input-tags border-light', placeholder: 'Select tags')
    = f.label :answered_from
    = f.date_field :start_from
    = f.label :answered_to
    = f.date_field :ends_from
    = f.submit 'Generate results'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= f.date_field :ends_from, as: :date, value: f.object.try(:strftime,"%d/%m/%Y") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime` function of ruby:

```
= f.date_field :start_from, value: @survey.start_from.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: @joeyk16 said it has not worked for him. But please let me know if i do changes in config/initializers/time.rb can i remove the dependency of system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my computer.

When im on someone elses computer it's `dd/mm/yyyy` when im on mine its `mm/dd/yyy` because my computer is American.